# postgres resultados duplicados en multiples inner join

Tags: postgresql, join

Tengo una db en postgres con la siguiente estructura.

```
tbl_predio
===========
predio_id
predio_nombre

tbl_propietario
==============
propietario_id
propietario_nombre
propietario_idpredio

tbl_linderos
===========
lindero_id
lindero_nombre
lindero_idpredio
```

El problema que tengo es que si tengo mas de un lindero para un predio me duplica los propietarios en una consulta con un join.

Es decir, suponiendo que para el predio de id 1 tengo un solo propietario de nombre John, y tengo dos linderos norte lindero1 y lindero2 al armar una consulta me devuelve en propietarios John,John.

La consulta la estoy haciendo así:

```
SELECT 
  p.predio_nombre AS predio,
  string_agg(pr.propietario_nombre,',') AS propietarios,
  string_agg(l.lindero_nombre,',') AS linderos

FROM tbl_predio p
  LEFT JOIN tbl_propietario pr ON pr.propietario_idpredio = p.predio_id
  LEFT JOIN tbl_linderos l ON l.lindero_idpredio = p.predio_id

WHERE
  p.predio_id = '1'

GROUP BY p.predio_id
```

el resultado que estoy obteniendo es

```
predio | propietarios | linderos
================================
predio1|john,john     | lindero1,lindero2
```

el resultado que quiero es

```
predio | propietarios | linderos
================================
predio1|john     | lindero1,lindero2
```

en resumen me está poniendo tantos propietarios como linderos, si tengo 3 linderos me va a poner 3 veces cada propietario existente en la db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías utilizar la palabra clave `distinct`, tal que solo retorno en la agregación los valores distintos:

```
SELECT 
  [...]
  string_agg(distinct(pr.propietario_nombre),',') AS propietarios,
  string_agg(distinct(l.lindero_nombre),',') AS linderos
[...]
```

Comment: Me funciona. Pero al agregar un order by me arroja el error '[42P10] en una gregación con Distinct, las expresiones en order by deben aparecer en la lista de argumentos.' el order by sería algo como "string_agg(pr.propietario_nombre,',' ORDER BY pr.propietario_id DESC) AS propietarios,"

Answer (score 0):

esto podria servirte

```
SELECT 
  p.predio_nombre AS predio,
  (select string_agg(pr1.propietario_nombre,','  ORDER BY pr1.propietario_id DESC) from tbl_propietario pr1 where pr1.propietario_idpredio=p.predio_id) AS propietarios,
  string_agg(l.lindero_nombre,',') AS linderos

FROM tbl_predio p
  LEFT JOIN tbl_linderos l ON l.lindero_idpredio = p.predio_id

WHERE
  p.predio_id = '1'

GROUP BY p.predio_id
```